# Problem with too verbose generated citations

Tags: bibtex

In the following MWE, bibtex generates different output for `\citep{}`, depending on which citations are used and which are not.
I assume that the problem is related to breaking ambiguity since the two authors with last name *Li* have different given names.

In the case of only using `\citep{}` once with `Li2009` or `Li2009a`, I get a citation `(Li et al., 2009)`, when using both, I get `(Li, Handsaker, Wysoker, Fennell, Ruan, Homer, Marth, Abecasis & Durbin 2009) (Li, Yu, Li, Lam, Yiu, Kristiansen & Wang 2009)`.

Is there any way to make the citation less verbose?
I realize that there has to be **some** way to discriminate different authors with the same last name, but is there another one? Like using the second author only?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Li2009,
    Publisher = {{Oxford Univ Press}},
    author = {Li, Heng and Handsaker, Bob and Wysoker, Alec and Fennell, Tim and Ruan, Jue and Homer, Nils and Marth, Gabor and Abecasis, Goncalo and Durbin, Richard},
    title = {{The sequence alignment/map format and SAMtools}},
    journal = {{Bioinformatics}},
    volume = {25},
    number = {16},
    pages = {2078-2079},
    year = {2009}
}

@article{Li2009a,
    Publisher = {{Oxford Univ Press}},
    author = {Li, Ruiqiang and Yu, Chang and Li, Yingrui and Lam, Tak-Wah and Yiu, Siu-Ming and Kristiansen, Karsten and Wang, Jun},
    title = {{SOAP2: an improved ultrafast tool for short read alignment}},
    journal = {{Bioinformatics}},
    volume = {25},
    number = {15},
    pages = {1966-1967},
    year = {2009}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[sort]{natbib}

\begin{document}

\citep{Li2009}
\citep{Li2009a}

\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{\jobname} % no file ending necessary

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not a solution but a suggestion: `biblatex` doesn't have this problem. Simply import the package with option `style=authoryear', add `\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}` to the preamble, change your `\citep` commands to `\parencite`, add `\printbibliography` at the end, and Bob's your uncle. I don't know the bibliographystyle `agsm`, so you'd have to find an equivalent for that.

Comment: My impression is that `agsm.bst` doesn't allow short citations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The disambiguation of multiple publications of the same author's last name in the same year is handled by the bibliography style.

Try `\bibliographystyle{APA}` to see the difference.

If you are required to take `agsm` then there might be a way to edit the respective .bst file, but thats beyond my skills `:)`

[image]